# Валидность HTML и тэг title

Tags: html5

Всем привет, при создании страниц столкнулся вот с какой проблемой. На главной странице с валидностью у меня всё нормально, а вот на остальных показывает одну ошибку. Ошибка заключается в теге title, потому что слова я пишу между открывающим и закрывающим тегом кириллицей.

Хотя на главной странице всё нормально и хотя между тегами я тоже пишу кириллицей. Пример:

```
<title>медиафайлы видео</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здравствуйте!
Дайте ссылку на сайт или же весь код.

Возможно, вам поможет это:

```
<title>медиафайлы видео</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
насколько мне известно, для html 4 а я делаю для html5, а там используеться тег мета сокращённо

Comment: а сайта как такового ещё нет, пока я делаю только страницы

Comment: Попробуйте поменять кодировку в Notepad++ на UTF-8 (без BOM).

Comment: у меня почему-та когда устанавливаю кодировку utf-8, кириллица кодируется, а сам сайт на денвере

Answer (score 0):

При использовании `<meta charset="utf-8">` вместо `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` в IE6 и некоторых других старых браузерах наблюдаются проблемы с кодировками! `!DOCTYPE html5` прописан в HTML документах?

Comment: Я про то же

Comment: да прописан, <!DOCTYPE html>, но про meta спасибо что сказали